# EU flight delayed, expenses reimbursement

Tags: delays

How do airlines proceed regarding expenses due to flights been delayed?

I am entitled to a monetary compensation of 400€. Is this compensation meant to cover expenses, or, are expenses reimbursed separately?

I spent 12+ extra hours at the airport, and my expenses are around 40€ (for lunch, coffee, snack, internet+printing). All of these were incurred after the official departure time. Are these reasonable expenses?

The airline is RyanAir, and I thought about asking them for vouchers. The queue was really long though, and it would have taken me 1 hour or more standing in line in an already horrible day.

Comment: The airline is responsible for your meals and accommodations. Whether they must accept your choice to forego the voucher, and whether the reason for making that choice matters, I do not know.

Answer (score 3):

The cash compensation is intended to compensate you for the *inconvenience* of losing time due to delay/cancellation.

As for your expenses at the airport: The airline is obliged to **provide you** with meals and refreshments, accommodation if necessary, and so forth. They get to choose *how* they provide that. If you refuse or ignore their offer of assistance (and the offer was reasonable). then whichever expenses you incur as a result of not taking their offer are not the airline's problem.

Answer (score 1):

While it would have likely been simpler to get the vouchers, you are entitled reasonable expenses, as specified, from RyanAir in addition to compensation.

If you go to their [EU261 claim form](https://eu261compensationclaims.ryanair.com/), the "Type of Claim" lists both compensation and expenses as options.

The [RyanAir EU261 FAQ](https://www.ryanair.com/us/en/useful-info/help-centre/faq-overview/flight-delays#0-4) further states

> If you are delayed you may be entitled to the following*:
>
> - meals and refreshments in reasonable relation to the waiting time;
> - two telephone calls or e-mails;
> - reasonable hotel accommodation where a stay of one or more nights becomes necessary;
> - reasonable transport between the airport and place of accommodation (hotel or other).

and

> Customers who wish to submit a travel/transport/refreshments expense/compensation claim following a flight cancellation or delay over 3 hours on arrival can click here to access the EU261 claim form.

Comment: But does someone have concrete information about what constitutes "reasonable"? I suppose my 40€ is acceptable (at least for me), but how far can you go?

Comment: @QuoraFeans: Internet and printing where **directly** related to the delay? Snacks are usually not considered. In my experience (see stranded people around me at airports) the missing launch is often replaced by a sandwich and a bottle of water or a 10 to 15 euro voucher. 12 hours is already enough for 2 (or three meals), so probably 40 is reasonable. Within 12 hours you didn't ask for voucher, so it is difficult to say "reasonable".

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi: well, I had to keep connected and print the new tickets. I wouldn't even be there if it was not for the delay. And the queue was really impressive. As I said above, it was RyanAir. Other flights of them were also delayed/cancelled. So, loads of angry people asking for solutions. Add to the top of it that I didn't really know it would be 12h. It was more a slippery delay where every 90 min they announced a new delay.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi You're explicitly entitled to reimbursement for "e-mails" so Internet access is part of that. Snacks are compensated ("refreshments"), though it seems to be a way to cheat you out of the reimbursement for a full meal.

Comment: @QuoraFeans: Often it is easier to use transfer desks/computers to print new tickets (and often it prints also the vouchers). But I'm not sure Ryanair support them. I agree with printing tickets: this backfires Ryanair which requires printed ticket from home (or a supplement).